# image manipulation - background position, src change and multiple images best practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about good manners with image manipulation.

I know three ways to do that, so I want know what is best (if anyone has some better way, be my guest in posting), using click's, mouseover's, doubleclick's and other events.

1. make a background and change the background position. ( this is what i use most )
2. change the `attr("src")`
3. work with imagem aready loaded but with hidden mode. ( this in my point of view is terrible )

Now I'm working with a lot of image manipulation, so I want to start doing the right thing.

what is the best way to manipulate image's using jquery ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific question you'd like to ask?

Comment: @Tim Rogers  yes, I want know what is best way to manipulate image's using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method is also called using sprites. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites Actually, the most efficient method is to place many icon sized images into one big 'sprite' image and just change the background image because:

- it loads much faster
- there are a lot less steps required behind the scenes to switch the image
- you don't have to preload images

There are tools available that automate this entire process for you.

Compass is my favourite: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/